# Updating Lots of Records at Once in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I've got a background job that I run about 5,000 of them every 10 minutes. Each job makes a request to an external API and then either adds new or updates existing records in my database. Each API request returns around 100 items, so every 10 minutes I am making 50,000 CREATE or UPDATE sql queries.

The way I handle this now is, each API item returned has a unique ID. I search my database for a post that has this id, and if it exists, it updates the model. If it doesn't exist, it creates a new one.

Imagine the api response looks like this:

```
[
  {
    external_id: '123',
    text: 'blah blah',
    count: 450
  },
  {
    external_id: 'abc',
    text: 'something else',
    count: 393
  }
]
```

which is set to the variable `collection`

Then I run this code in my parent model:

```
class ParentModel < ApplicationRecord
  def update
    collection.each do |attrs|
      child = ChildModel.find_or_initialize_by(external_id: attrs[:external_id], parent_model_id: self.id)
      child.assign_attributes attrs
      child.save if child.changed?
    end
  end
end
```

Each of these individual calls is extremely quick, but when I am doing 50,000 in a short period of time it really adds up and can slow things down.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way I can handle this, I was thinking of doing something instead like:

```
class ParentModel < ApplicationRecord
  def update
    eager_loaded_children = ChildModel.where(parent_model_id: self.id).limit(100)
    collection.each do |attrs|
      cached_child = eager_loaded_children.select {|child| child.external_id == attrs[:external_id] }.first
      if cached_child
        cached_child.update_attributes attrs
      else
        ChildModel.create attrs
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Essentially I would be saving the lookups and instead doing a bigger query up front (this is also quite fast) but making a tradeoff in memory. But this doesn't seem like it would be that much time, maybe slightly speeding up the lookup part, but I'd still have to do 100 updates and creates.

Is there some kind of way I can do batch updates that I'm not thinking of? Anything else obvious that could make this go faster, or reduce the amount of queries I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
collection2 = collection.map { |c| [c[:external_id], c.except(:external_id)]}.to_h

def update
  ChildModel.where(external_id: collection2.keys).each |cm| do
    ext_id = cm.external_id
    cm.assign_attributes collection2[ext_id]
    cm.save if cm.changed?
    collection2.delete(ext_id)
  end
  if collection2.present?
    new_ids = collection2.keys
    new = collection.select { |c| new_ids.include? c[:external_id] }
    ChildModel.create(new)
  end
end
```

Better because

- fetches all required records all at once
- creates all new records at once

You can use `update_columns` if you don't need `callbacks`/`validations`
Only drawback, more ruby code manipulation which I think is a good tradeoff for db queries..

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense. I definitely like the idea of doing all the creates at once. The only thing I could forsee being an issue would be `ChildModel.where(external_id: collection2.keys)`, `collection2.keys` could potentially be up to 100 keys long, wouldn't that not be a very efficient query with so many keys in the array?

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem, I have fetched 1000s of columns with `where` query..however, it would matter if the column is not indexed..it would be better if you index `external_id`.